# Free embedded database which support encryption (.NET)

Tags: database, encryption, embedded-database

I'm looking for a free embedded database for .NET (C#), which supports encryption. Preferably some sort of TDE (Transparent Data Encryption) using good encryption protocols (like AES 256).

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: Do you already have an idea where you can store the key? AES-256 is very strong, but that does not mean that your system has the same strength.

Comment: Key will be calculated from user input and some other data. Well it can be AES-128, or something "descent" (not easily cracked if you only have access to database file and application & database aren't running).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly nobody answered. Well later on I found out that **SQL CE 3.5 and 4.0** both support encryption, are free and embedded and support C# (.NET).